# Dynamically add routes with openui5

Tags: sapui5

How could I include file to manifest.json that will contain all routing I want? I don't want to use addRoutes() because I want routes to be stored in json file so I could edit this file and save and there will be new set of routes applied. I just don't want routing to be hardcoded in manifest. Any hints, ideas?

Comment: read your json file in component before router gets initialized, then parse this file and call "addRoutes", afterwards initialize your router. But to be honest I cannot understand what's the difference between hardcoding them in manifest or other json file?

Comment: because when it will be in other file I will allow users to edit routing via GUI